# Injecting constructor in jersey

Tags: java, web, jersey, guice, grizzly

I'm trying to inject the constructor of resource class using Guice. Meanwhile  i have used GrizzlyWebServer as a server to handle the reqquest from the resource class. Below i've given some of the codes and errors I'm having.

GoogleModule class:

```
public class GoogleModule extends AbstractModule {

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(Interface.class).to(Implementation.class);
  }
}
```

Resource class

```
@Path("/path")
public class ResourceClass {
  Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResourceClass.class);
  private final Interface interface;

  GConnection con = new GConnection();

  @Inject
  public ResourceClass(Interface interface) {
    this.interface = interface;
  }

  @GET
  @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
  public List<Object> getObjects() {
    return  interface.list();
  }
}
```

and before starting the grizzly server I've call this statement.

```
 Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new GoogleModule());
 webserver.startServer();
```

after this set up i've i found the following error.

```
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public        com.motilink.services.ResourceClass(Interface ) at parameter index 0
 Jul 3, 2013 9:52:36 AM com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter doService
SEVERE: service exception:
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.loadServlet(ServletAdapter.java:451)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.doService(ServletAdapter.java:390)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.service(ServletAdapter.java:347)
at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapterChain.service(GrizzlyAdapterChain.java:186)
at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:824)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:721)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1014)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:220)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:530)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:511)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that Guice can inject constructors with Jersey. Try switching to injecting the field instead.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're running through a servlet you need to make sure that Guice is hooked in correctly so that resources are created with injection rather than instantiated directly.  The way you have your code now the injector is not used to create the new instance of the resource and hence your error.

There are details on how to set this up on the [Guice Wiki](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule).

Comment: Thanks but i've solved it. I forget to add the adapter with injector in the server side!!